# adding single-spa to vue apps which are using module federation fails

Tags: vue.js, webpack, micro-frontend, single-spa

I have a failed case using SingleSpa with vue apps. Vue apps are using module federation to share components.

The case is as follow:

1. `App1` uses module federation and exposes one component.
2. `App2` uses module federation to read the exposed component from `App1`

The above works as long as `single-spa` is not added to the projects. So `App2` will use the `App1` components.

But when `single-spa` is added, `App2` no longer works as standalone, it cannot apparently load the `App1` components anymore with the following error:

```
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk vendors-node_modules_vue_vue-loader-v15_lib_runtime_componentNormalizer_js-node_modules_vueti-2692ba failed.
```

Also on the `root` project which is a `single-spa` container, it loads `App1` successfully but can't load `App2`.

I assume that this can be a webpack config which I'm missing either in App1 or in App2.

Here is an example repository where SingleSpa is added to the projects and you can see App2 doesn't load anymore unless you disable `ModuleFederation` or remove `SingleSpa`

**Example:** https://github.com/farhadnowzari/singlespa-module-federation-failure